# Active Notch Filter Simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, active-filter, falstad

I need to build an Active twin- notch filter that will filter out 60Hz. I am following the schematic bellow:

[image]

To test the schematic, I am simulating it on Falstad Circuit Simulator, but the 60Hz is not being filtered out.

[Here is the link to the simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%20188.49690236434094%2050%205%2043%0AR%20144%20160%2096%20160%200%201%2060%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20208%20160%20288%20160%200%2010000000%0Aw%20144%20176%20144%20240%200%0Aw%20144%20160%20144%20176%200%0Aw%20144%20304%20144%20240%200%0Ac%20144%20304%20288%20304%200%202.7e-10%20-7.872164311672611%0Aw%20208%20160%20176%20160%200%0Aw%20176%20160%20160%20160%200%0Aw%20160%20160%20144%20160%200%0Ar%20288%20304%20288%20240%200%205000000%0Ac%20288%20160%20288%20240%200%205.4e-10%20-2.9711730182343636%0Ar%20288%20160%20416%20160%200%2010000000%0Aa%20416%20144%20528%20144%200%2015%20-15%201000000%0Aw%20528%20144%20528%20224%200%0Aw%20288%20240%20384%20240%200%0Aw%20528%20224%20528%20240%200%0Aw%20528%20240%20384%20240%200%0Aw%20528%20144%20528%2080%200%0Aw%20416%20128%20416%2080%200%0Aw%20416%2080%20480%2080%200%0Aw%20528%2080%20480%2080%200%0Ac%20288%20304%20416%20304%200%202.7e-10%20-1.9298182752046245%0Aw%20416%20160%20416%20304%200%0Ao%2017%2064%200%20551%2020%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0A).

Could any tell me where I am going wrong ?

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: For your component values, I get 59Hz for \$f_0\$. Also, there's no amplitude indication on the simulation output. No filter gets rid of 100% of the target signal. It could just be the input signal attenuated by 40dB or something, especially since it's off to one side by about 1.7%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit doesn't work for me either and I've bread borded it.
It appears that the Q is so high it the notch depth amplitude disappears.
Try reducing the feedback it worked for me! 
Put a 10K pot between your op-amp output and ground, buffer it with another op-amp (non inverting) and use the output of this opamp as your feedback point.
the 10K pot will give your a variable Q.

Besst regards 
Ray

Answer (score 1):

This "simulator" does not seem to be very suited to simulate this kind of circuit. It looks like it can only do a time simulation. To see that 60 Hz is suppressed (it cannot be removed completely !) you would have to do many simulations and for many frequencies and plot the output's amplitude.

In a "real" circuit simulator like [Qucs](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/) (free software !) or LTspice you can do an AC simulation which plots a figure like plot B in your question.